# Detect changes within a service in another service (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, rxjs, observable, angular-services

I've only been working with angular for a few months now and currently overwhelmed with the services. I'm using 3 angular services that interact with each other. An authService, a configService, and a guardService.

In my guardService, the **checkBusinessCase(bcase)** method checks the current business case and sets it with the method **this.authService.setActiveBusinessCase(bcase)** inside my AuthService.

The guardService looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { UserAuthService } from './user-auth.service';
import { Constants } from '../../constants';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class BcaseRequiredGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: UserAuthService) {

  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (next.data['bcase']) {
      return this.checkBusinessCase(next.data['bcase']);
    }
    if (next.data['bcaseRegExp']) {
      return this.checkBusinessCase(new RegExp(next.data['bcaseRegExp']));
    }
    this.router.navigate([Constants.routing.error, 'invalidBusinessCase']);
    return false;

  }

  checkBusinessCase(bcase): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
      map(isLoggedIn => {
        const accept = isLoggedIn && this.authService.hasBusinessCase(bcase);
        if (accept) {
          console.log('This guard approved that the Business case ' + bcase + ' is assigned to ' + this.authService.user.user_name);
          this.authService.setActiveBusinessCase(bcase);
        } else {
          console.log('This guard approved that the Business case ' + bcase + ' is not assigned to ' + this.authService.user.user_name);
          this.router.navigate([Constants.routing.home]);
        }
        return accept;
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error(Constants.errors.loginCheckFailed, err);
        this.router.navigate([Constants.routing.error, 'loginCheckFailed']);
        return of(false);
      }));
  }

}
```

Exactly this business case I need now in my configService within the **getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage()** method. When I try to access it with **this.authService.activeBusinessCase** I get undefined because the configService is called before the authService.

The configService looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import 'moment/locale/de';
import { UserAuthService } from 'app/auth/user-auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

  defaultLanguage = 'en';
  activeBusinessCase = '';

  languages = {
    en: 'English',
    de: 'German',
    es: 'Spanish',
    ja: 'Japanese',
    pt: 'Portuguese'
  };

  // Business cases with available translation files
  businessCases = {
    case1: '_case1',
    case2: '_case2',
    case3: '_case3'
  };

  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private authService: UserAuthService
  ) {

  }
  // Get business case specific language
  // TODO: Get currently logged in business case
  getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage(){
    const browserLang = this.translate.getBrowserLang();
    console.log('BROWSER LANGUAGE: ', browserLang);
    console.log('ACTIVE BUSINESS CASE: ', this.activeBusinessCase);
    if (this.languages.hasOwnProperty(browserLang) && this.activeBusinessCase !== undefined) {
      switch (this.activeBusinessCase) {
        case 'CASE1':
          return browserLang.concat(this.businessCases.case1);
        case 'CASE2':
          return browserLang.concat(this.businessCases.case2);
        case 'CASE3':
          return browserLang.concat(this.businessCases.case2);
        default:
          return browserLang;
      }
    } else if (this.languages.hasOwnProperty(browserLang) && this.activeBusinessCase === undefined) {
      console.log('No currently active business case.');
      return browserLang;
    } else {
      return this.defaultLanguage;
    }
  }

}
```

And this is the authService, where the activeBusinessCase property whose value I need is set:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Constants } from '../../constants';
import { EMPTY, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { translate } from '../shared/translation-util';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { LoginError } from '../model/auth/LoginError';
import { User } from '../model/auth/User';
import { UiInfo } from '../model/auth/UiInfo';
import { ChangePasswordError } from '../model/auth/ChangePasswordError';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { catchError, map, mergeMap, publishReplay, refCount, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoginResponse } from '../model/auth/LoginResponse';

@Injectable()
export class UserAuthService {

  activeBusinessCase: string;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private pls: PathLocationStrategy,
              private titleService: Title) {

  }

  setActiveBusinessCase(bcase: string) {
    this.activeBusinessCase = bcase;
    this.setTitle(bcase);
  }

}
```

How can I get the current business case (activeBusinessCase) in my configService?

---

**UPDATE:**

After adopting the changes of ***fridoo*** and adjusting them to my needs, everything looks more logical now. But now I have error messages elsewhere that I can not handle. Here are the broken lines of code and error messages in the console.

In my http.service.ts:

```
  getResource(key: string, lang: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Accept': 'text/html'});
    return this.httpClient.get('/resources/' + key,
      {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'text',
        params: new HttpParams()
          .set('businessCase', this.authService.activeBusinessCase ? this.authService.activeBusinessCase :
            environment.default_business_case)
          .set('lang', lang)
      }).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return this.translateService.get('Not-available').pipe(
          map(res => '<h4 style="text-align: center">' + res + '</h4>'));
      })
    );
  }
```

Error-Message:

> Property 'activeBusinessCase' is private and only accessible within class 'UserAuthService'.

My user-auth.service.ts

```
  login(name: string, password: string, imTid: string): Observable<UiInfo> {
    return this.loginWithBackend(name, password, imTid).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.user.user_name = translate('default-user');
        // TODO: Check if loggedoff is obsolete?
        if (this.loggedOff) {
          this.pls.back();
        } else if (this.redirectUrl) {
          this.router.navigate([this.redirectUrl]);
          this.redirectUrl = null;
          console.log(Constants.texts.loginSuccessRedirect);

        } else {
          console.log('Active Business Case', this.activeBusinessCase);
          if (this.activeBusinessCase) {
            this.router.navigate([Constants.routing.explorer + this.activeBusinessCase.toLowerCase()]);
          } else {
            const err = new LoginError('Business case is missing');
            throw err;
          }
        }
        this.loggedOff = false;
      }));
```

Error-Message:

> Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject'.

My home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  routing = Constants.routing;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: UserAuthService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate([Constants.routing.explorer + this.authService.activeBusinessCase.toLowerCase()]);
  }

}
```

Error-Message:

> Property 'activeBusinessCase' is private and only accessible within class 'UserAuthService'.

Comment: How do you use `getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage()`? Where do you call it? When do you need the returned value? I would say this is a classic case where you'd use Observables with your `activeBusinessCase` probably being a `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: @fridoo getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage() is called within my AppComponent inside a initLanguage() function like: this.translate(getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage());

Comment: `getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage()` should return an Observable as it's depending on an async action itself (the change of `activeBusinessCase` from undefined to having a value). The question is how you would want that Observable to behave. Should it only emit one value when `activeBusinessCase` has a value or should it emit mutiple values as `activeBusinessCase` changes from undefined to having a value? Should it emit every time the `activeBusinessCase` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `activeBusinessCase` is set asynchronously and you want to be notified about value changes in another part of your app it should be a `Subject`. Use a `BehaviorSubject` so that you'll immediately get the current value upon subscription.

```ts
// ----- UserAuthService -----

public activeBusinessCase$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

setActiveBusinessCase(bcase: string) {
  this.activeBusinessCase.next(bcase);
  this.setTitle(bcase);
}
```

Listen to value changes of the `activeBusinessCase$` in your ConfigurationService and map the incoming values to the language you want to return.

```ts
// ----- ConfigurationService -----

// will emit a new language every time activeBusinessCase changes,
// this behavior could be changed depending on your specific needs
getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage$(): Observable<string> {
  return this.authService.activeBusinessCase$
    .pipe(
      // use 'distinctUntilChanged' to only emit values that are different from the previous,
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(abc => this.getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage(abc))
    );     
}

private getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage(activeBusinessCase: string): string {
  // no changes here apart from the input parameter - I omitted the code for brevity
  // use the parameter activeBusinessCase instead of this.activeBusinessCase here
}
```

Subscribe to `getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage$` where you need the language.

```ts
// ----- AppComponent -----

initLanguage() {
  this.configService.getAutoConfiguredBCLanguage$()
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)) // unsubscribe when the component gets destroyed
    .subscribe(lang => {
      // use the language here
    });
}

private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

onDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

A `BehaviorSubject` has the function `getValue` which returns the last value emitted by the `BehaviorSubject`. You could use this function to get the current `activeBusinessCase` but only do so if you know what you are doing, i.e. if you realy mean to get the current value at the **specific time** you call `getValue`. Remember that you're dealing with asynchronous actions in you app. If you want to be sure to get the value of `activeBusinessCase$` after it has been set by calling `this.authService.setActiveBusinessCase` you have to subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject`. If you don't care whether `activeBusinessCase$` was already set and just want to use the current value of `activeBusinessCase$` you can use `getValue` (which then might return `null` which was set as the initial value of `activeBusinessCase$`).

My suggestion:

```ts
// ---- HomeComponent ----

ngOnInit() {
  // To navigate to a route once the activeBusinessCase has a non null value
  // subscribe but only take the first non null element and no further values afterwards
  this.authService.activeBusinessCase$
    .pipe(first(Boolean))
    .subscribe(bc => this.router.navigate([Constants.routing.explorer + bc.toLowerCase()]));
}

// ---- SmagHttpService & UserAuthService ----

// Don't subscribe to activeBusinessCase$ in here!! Instead use
this.authService.activeBusinessCase$.getValue()
// when you need the current value (which might not have been set yet, 
// but you already have null checks here and if this part of your app worked before 
// there will be no differences)

// Example:
const businessCase = this.authService.activeBusinessCase$.getValue();
if (businessCase) {
  this.router.navigate([Constants.routing.explorer + businessCase.toLowerCase()]);
}

businessCase ? businessCase : environment.default_business_case
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will try this on Monday and give you a feedback.

I still have a question. What is the difference between a Subject and BehaviorSubject? I only knew Subject so far.

And why doesn't my version work? I thought services are singletons and for this reason I would have to be able to read out the value of the property activeBusinessCase from my authServices everywhere? or not? Very confusing at the moment..

Comment: A `BehaviorSubject` has a current value which it will emit immediately to any new subscriber. A `Subject`doesn't have a current value. Your version doesn't work because it isn't guaranteed that the `activeBusinessCase` will be written before it is read. You set `activeBusinessCase` at some time and read `activeBusinessCase` at some other time, but don't know which will happen before the other. This is a classic use case for Observables. You can subscribe to value changes before your Observable (or Subject) has a value you care about, then when your Subject receives a value you will be notified

Comment: I have adopted your changes and adapted them to my needs. It looks logical now, but now I have error messages elsewhere that I can not handle. I've updated my question above and added the broken lines of code and error messages in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could probably use the function `getValue` from `BehaviorSubject`. Please see my added text at the bottom and the code updates in `UserAuthService`. If your app worked before it should work by using `getValue` in the code where you currently get compiler errors. But I'm not sure how you want your app to behave. Does `this.authService.setActiveBusinessCase` get called multiple times while your app is running? Do you want your app to actively react whenever `activeBusinessCase` changes?

Comment: I fixed the error messages by making a subscription and then calling toLowerCase funtion in the subscription callback.

Now I have a bigger problem. I have a guard service which sets the activeBusinessCase within the canActivate method by calling the this.authService.setActiveBusinessCase(bcase) function based on the URL at the first login. This causes the problem that the activeBusinessCase is set again and again, so I have an endless loop and the browser crashes / freezes.

Comment: I thought that something like this might happen. You haven't yet answered all my question! Please answer my questions from my second comment to your question and my second comment to this answer. How do you want your app to behave to changes to `activeBusinessCase`?

Comment: When a user logs in to my app, he already receives an activeBusinessCase. This is set during the login in the canActivate method. After he is logged in, specific json files for translations are taken on the basis of the activeBusinessCase. But now the user has the possibility to change the business cases by clicking on another business case while navigating. So the business case keeps changing as the user navigates and uses the application. For this reason, the activeBusinessCase must always be up to date, so that the correct translation (json files) can be taken.

Comment: And currently because of the guard service, which engages during the login process, an endless loop occurs. If I can fix this, everything should work.

Comment: I will prepare a plunker by tomorrow, containing all the relevant files. So you have a better overview. Otherwise, it is really complicated to explain.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One more question. Do you ever want to actively do something when a change to the `activeBusinessCase` is detected? (e.g. load different translation files). Or does your app just passively use the current `activeBusinessCase` whenever it needs to?

Comment: I have uploaded the relevant folder structure and files because it did not work with the Plunker. I've also cleaned up the files to the bare minimum, leaving only areas inside with the active business case. The tips that you have given me so far are already implemented. To your last question: I always want to load specific translation files based on the activeBusinessCase, which I keeps changing while the user navigates. If the activeBusiness changes, the corresponding file should be loaded. Here is the download link, I hope you can do something with it and help me: https://ufile.io/q0wd3

Comment: I updated the code im my answer for UserAuthService, ConfigurationService, HomeComponent & SmagHttpService. It should work this way.  In `UserAuthService` `login` - what do you do in your app if you throw an error here. How is `login` used?

Comment: I've adopted your changes, but I can not test them until tomorrow in the office. As soon as I looked over it tomorrow, I'll give you another feedback. Thank you!

Comment: So .. I have implemented your tips, however, I still have the problem with the endless loop. In my bcase-required.guard.ts, at line 35, this.authService.setActiveBusinessCase (bcase); gets called, which calls the method setActiveBusinessCase in the user-auth.service.ts. So I can not log in anymore, because after clicking the login button endless businesscases are added, causing the browser to crash. If I comment out the line in the bcase-required.guard.ts file, I can login again..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189514/discussion-between-fridoo-and-codehan25).